# Boundary conditions to be used in simulating plasmonics

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, photons, simulations, plasmon

I am very new to this field and trying to understand the boundary conditions usage when simulating plasmonic structures. I use CST studio suite for EM simulations.I am not understanding exactly what kind of boundary conditions to be used along what kind of symmetry planes.

Answer (score 0):

I never used CST, but I usually put PML boundary conditions around the edges of the simulation domain. The symmetry planes will depend on what exactly is the geometry of the plasmonic structure you are simulating.

Answer (score 0):

Like ptomato said, it depends on the symmetry of the situation. Perfectly Matched Layers (PMLs) typically refer to the 'end' of your simulation area. Any EM wave moving through them is completely absorbed, not reflected. Another type of boundary is Metallic boundary, which is typically only reflecting, and this would be comparable to trapping your system inside a metal box (maybe a waveguide). Finally, periodic boundaries assume your structure repeats in a certain direction. Here is an example with PMLs on the top and bottom of the box:
[image]